# Configure specific breaker for route with Resilience4j in Spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, resilience4j

I attempt to configure Resilience4j in my spring cloud gateway without success.
All that I find is for Hystrix or with pure java.

I have configured the gateway to transfer request on my service, that is ok.

But impossible to configure resilience4j on it. I have a good artifact in reactive for R4J.

Configuration of Resilience4j is different in spring cloud API and gateway?

See my configuration file.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: helloworld_service
          uri: "https://localhost:8080"
          predicates:
            - Path=/helloworld/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/helloworld/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: helloworld
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          useInsecureTrustManager: true

# RESILIENCE4J PROPERTIES
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    configs:
      default:
        #registerHealthIndicator: true
        ringBufferSizeInClosedState: 10
        ringBufferSizeInHalfOpenState: 3
        automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
        waitDurationInOpenStateMillis: 2000
        failureRateThreshold: 50
        eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
    instances:
      helloworld:
        baseConfig: default
        ringBufferSizeInClosedState: 5
```

My dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And the error generated:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name CircuitBreaker
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name CircuitBreaker
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: Hi Bilak,

not...

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use external configuration for Resiulience4j circuit breaker , you need to add the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
       </dependency>
```

Then in your spring gateway application , inject the loaded Circuitbreaker registery with ur external configuration in spring cloud factory :

```java
    @Bean
    public ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory(CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry) {
        ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory = new ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory();
        reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory.configureCircuitBreakerRegistry(circuitBreakerRegistry);
        return reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory;
    }
```

Then add it your external circuit breaker configuration in the applciation yml file for exmaple:

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
      slidingWindowSize: 10
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
      automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
      waitDurationInOpenState: 2s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
      recordExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - java.io.IOException
      ignoreExceptions:
        - java.lang.IllegalStateException
    shared:
      slidingWindowSize: 100
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 30
      waitDurationInOpenState: 1s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
      ignoreExceptions:
        - java.lang.IllegalStateException
  instances:
    backendA:
      baseConfig: default
```

enable circuit breaker filter in your route with the configured circuit breaker name  , example:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  output.ansi.enabled: ALWAYS
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: test-service-withResilient4j
          uri: http://localhost:8091
          predicates:
            - Path=/testService/**
          filters:
            - CircuitBreaker=backendA
            - RewritePath=/testService/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
```

and it should be protected now with ur external configured circuit breaker , other wise you can just configure it through code config approach with customizer

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, I'm in holiday for the moment, I feed back to all the responses quickly.

Comment: I am actually suffering from the exact same issue. I have tried these steps but I receive `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'backendA' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.discovery.DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator$DelegatingServiceInstance' - maybe not public or not valid?`

Comment: @DarylRobbins do u have code sample i can check on github or something ?

Comment: code sample here :https://github.com/Romeh/spring-cloud-gateway-resilience4j

Comment: How do you associate the breaker instance to the route in non-property based RouteLocator?  filters: - CircuitBreaker=auth-service

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in current spring-cloud-gateway `Hoxton.RELEASE` autoconfiguration. You can workaround it with following configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class Resilience4JConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FallbackHeadersGatewayFilterFactory fallbackHeadersGatewayFilterFactory() {
        return new FallbackHeadersGatewayFilterFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringCloudCircuitBreakerFilterFactory resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory(
            ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveCircuitBreakerFactory,
            ObjectProvider<DispatcherHandler> dispatcherHandlers) {
        return new SpringCloudCircuitBreakerResilience4JFilterFactory(reactiveCircuitBreakerFactory, dispatcherHandlers);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Bilak,
Thanks for your answer.
It'seems that I can compile with your solution.
But my resilience4j configuration is not used :(
Do I need to add another configuration than it's on my question?

And with the configuration, the application doesn't find an instance of ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory. Is it not auto-create by spring?

Comment: configuration for R4j of SCG is [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) it's different from one you used

Comment: Thanks, Bilak, my default Circuit Breaker seems usable.
Just a little one if you agree.

I created a custom Circuit breaker to override some properties of the default, but i don't understand how to select this for my route. I add the name of this configuration in args of the route but is not use.

```yaml
fitlers:
   - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: helloworldCircuitBreaker
```

```java
setCircuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.custom().minimumNumberOfCalls(10).failureRateThreshold(20).build()), "helloworldCircuitBreaker");
```

Comment: maybe post full example of that config, it's not very readable here in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Tanks Bilak for your patience.

My configuration of Resilience4j:

```java
@Configuration
public class Resilience4JConfiguration {

    /**
     * Default Resilience4j circuit breaker configuration
     */
    @Bean
    public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
        return factory -> factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.custom().minimumNumberOfCalls(5).failureRateThreshold(20).build())
                .build());
    }

    @Bean
    public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> helloworldCircuitBreaker(){
        return factory -> {
          factory.configure(builder -> builder.circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults()).build()
                  .setCircuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.custom().minimumNumberOfCalls(10).failureRateThreshold(20).build())
                  , "helloworldCircuitBreaker");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> accountCircuitBreaker(){
        return factory -> {
            factory.configure(builder -> builder.circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults()).build(), "accountCircuitBreaker");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public FallbackHeadersGatewayFilterFactory fallbackHeadersGatewayFilterFactory() {
        return new FallbackHeadersGatewayFilterFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringCloudCircuitBreakerFilterFactory resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory(
            ReactiveCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveCircuitBreakerFactory,
            ObjectProvider<DispatcherHandler> dispatcherHandlers) {
        return new SpringCloudCircuitBreakerResilience4JFilterFactory(reactiveCircuitBreakerFactory, dispatcherHandlers);
    }
}
```

My application.yaml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: helloworld_service
          uri: "https://localhost:8080"
          predicates:
            - Path=/helloworldservice/**
          filters:
            - CircuitBreaker
```

With this configuration, the default configuration it uses correctly.

But if I attempt to precise the specific Circuit Breaker, no configuration is used (no default and no the helloworldCircuitBreaker)

Configuration with specific Circuit Breaker:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: helloworld_service
          uri: "https://localhost:8080"
          predicates:
            - Path=/helloworldservice/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
            args:
              name: helloworldCircuitBreaker
```

Comment: well I think you need to add customizer so `factory.addCircuitBreakerCustomizer` in CB examples. Then it could work.

Comment: could you please help how to create Customizer CircuitBreaker with customizer config?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following dependency is added:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now in your spring gateway application, create the bean:

```
@Bean
public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
    return factory -> factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
            .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults())
            .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom().timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(4)).build()).build());
}
```

Now, the application.yml should look like

```
spring:
application:
  name: CLOUD-GATEWAY
cloud:
  gateway:
    routes:
    - id: order-service
      uri: lb://ORDER-SERVICE
      predicates:
      - Path=/orders**
      filters:
        - name: CircuitBreaker
          args:
            name: order-service
            fallbackuri: forward:/fallback/orders
```

Comment: Only adding the dependency `spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j` instead of `spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j` worked for me.